# Putting factors together in data frame R

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2

I have got a data frame of which one column contains 5 factors and I have used `ggplot2` to plot a `facet_grid` and this plots 5 graphs with each one of them containing data from each of the factors. However I want to include an extra facet that contains the combined data of all the factors. How would I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `facet_grid()` you can set `margins = TRUE`. Shown with standard dataset below:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mpg, aes(hwy, cty)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(~ drv, margins = TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for your answer! How would I move the "(all)" facet all the way to the left?

Comment: I don't know honestly. There doesn't seem to be an obvious argument that controls this.